# Proxy calls to UICollectionView in Swift. Being able to pass Proxy as a method argument

Tags: swift, proxy, uicollectionview, duck-typing

**Code:**

```
class ColletionProxy: UICollectionView {

  weak var collectionView: UICollectionView?

  init(collectionView: UICollectionView) {
    super.init(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    self.collectionView = collectionView
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView!.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let dataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource = MyCustomCollectionViewDataSource()

let realCollectionView = UICollectionView()
let proxy = CollectionProxy(realCollectionView)

let SUPERCELL = dataSource.collectionView(proxy, cellForItem at indexPath)
```

I want to make `ColletionProxy` not to be a subclass of the `UICollectionView` while being able to use it the way shown in **Usage**

To be precise, I would like to have a set of methods in the `Proxy` class mimicking the methods of the `UICollectionView` to be able to drop in the Proxy class instead of the `UICollectionView` when necessary.

Comment: You can try with NSProxy class. I've used it only once, in Obj-C, but I think it may work in Swift on class with NSObject root (which UICollectionView has). On pure Swift class it may be impossible, but I hope someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: Will definitely try it! Currently I have to create a fake `UICollectionView` and use it for proxying. It's not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: @MaciejKozieł NSProxy approach worked well! However, I had to do two things: 1. Use `ObjC` to implement the proxying behavior (`NSProxy.init` is unavailable in Swift). And, 2. use a weird type cast to avoid runtime crash when trying to cast `proxy as! UICollectionView` directly. Please, see my answer for the details, and feel free to improve it if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Code I've finished with:**

**Proxy:**

```
#import "CollectionViewProxy.h"

@interface CollectionViewProxy()
@property (weak, nonatomic) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@end

@implementation CollectionViewProxy
- (instancetype)initWithCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
  if (self) {
    self.collectionView = collectionView;
  }
  return self;
}

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  return cell;
}

- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass {
  if (aClass == [UICollectionView class]) {
    return YES;
  }
  return [super isKindOfClass:aClass];
}

@end
```

**ComposedDataSource:**

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let ds = dataSources.first!
    // let ds = GET THE RELEVANT DATASOURCE HERE
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = ((CollectionViewProxy(collectionView: collectionView) as Any) as! UICollectionView) // Any way to avoid this cast?
    return ds.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)
  }
```

Is there any way to avoid this cast through `Any`?

`let collectionView: UICollectionView = ((CollectionViewProxy(collectionView: collectionView) as Any) as! UICollectionView)`

Answer (score 0):

**Even better approach, no need to do Objective-C<>Swift bridging:**

```
import UIKit

protocol CollectionViewProtocol {
  func dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
}

extension UICollectionView: CollectionViewProtocol {}

protocol ComposableCollectionDataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: CollectionViewProtocol, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: CollectionViewProtocol, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
}

class MyDataSource: NSObject, ComposableCollectionDataSource {

  // MARK: Real implementation can be used with any class conforming to CollectionViewProtocol

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: CollectionViewProtocol, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "test", for: indexPath)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: CollectionViewProtocol, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  // MARK: Methods "Mirroring" UICollectionViewDataSource

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.collectionView(collectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: section)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return self.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)
  }
}

class Proxy: CollectionViewProtocol {
  private let hiddenCollectionView = UICollectionView()

  func dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // Transform IndexPath Here
    let transformedIndexPath = indexPath
    return hiddenCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: transformedIndexPath)
  }
}


let dataSource = MyDataSource()
let realCollectionView = UICollectionView()
let fakeCollectionView = Proxy()

let cell = dataSource.collectionView(realCollectionView, cellForItemAt: IndexPath())
let anotherCell = dataSource.collectionView(fakeCollectionView, cellForItemAt: IndexPath())
```